# How do you list all processes in SunStudio attach debugger dialog?

Tags: c++, cgi, sunstudio

I'm using SunStudio 12.3 to debug a C++ CGI.  SunStudio runs under my userid, and I have ownership of the executable.  However, the CGI process runs with the web server's id, not mine.

When I try to attach to the process, I see only processes running under my id.  Thus, the CGI is not listed.  Is there a way to list all processes, or processes belonging to specific ids other than mine?

Comment: What is the OS? If linux, try runuser: http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

Comment: OS is Solaris 11.  Subsequent to asking the question I found some info on setuid, aka the sticky-bit permission setting.  Using that we theoretically would be able able to run Solaris Studio as my user but with superuser permissions...however, due to OS restrictions on using dynamic linking with the sticky-bit, Solaris Studio can't even start with that permission, as it can't find its libraries/dependent executables/whatever.  I've been tackling the problem from the other end: getting webserver7 to execute CGI as a specified user.